# textfield text or placeholder is not align in centre, it seem left side has white spaces, how can I align in center in iOS

Tags: ios, uitextfield

textfield text or placeholder is not align in centre, it seem left side has white spaces, how can I align in center in iOS.
Every where I add textfield it behave strangely.

[image]

Comment: there is something wrong in your code. By default textfield show from left side. Remove and again add textfiled. Perhaps it resolve your problem

Comment: are you using autolayout or you are setting it with frame?

Comment: Mind adding your `textField` initialisation code?

Comment: @ShahbazAkram  I have done all ways , remove and add another, also done with code also but can't resolve.

Comment: Break the View and then check position of textfield.

Comment: position is fine but text in editable area is not allign, this the issue

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using property textAlignment? 
  textfield.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft/Center;
If you use autolayout, then try vertically alignment based on the button being used. 
If you could provide your code for the textfield (if initialized in code), it would be more clearer.

Comment: here is my code
    txtVehicleRegNumbr.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
txtVehicleRegNumbr.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;

    txtVehicleRegNumbr.contentMode= UIViewContentModeCenter;